# Enter section name in the url browser to a website single page?

Tags: jquery, web

I created a website single page divided into grids, each grid contains a menu item ...
I would like once you select the grid (a menu item) to enter the section (which opens from the top with the contents inside) next to the url in the browser menu item to appear.

example:

before you click on the menu item: namesite.com
after clicking on the menu item: namesite.com / about

Currently if I go to click on a menu item opens the correct course section, however the url of the browser remains unchanged or namesite.com

What is the best way to do what I wrote above?

Comment: sounds like you need some sort of 'routing' system. Have a look at http://millermedeiros.github.com/crossroads.js/  or http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/ depending on your requirements

Answer (score 0):

`pushState` is what you're after.

http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate?6dde2bc8

Comment: it is what it does for me ... but a good tutorial with examples where you can find? to better understand the operation.